# Two classes in one Java Spring Form

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc

is it possible, and if yes, how is it possible to create one object and put it inside other object using Java Spring Form? Because I need to create "Engine" object and put it inside "Car" object. Here are my codes of "Engine" and "Car":

```
public class Engine {
    private float volume;
    private int id;

    public float getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public void setVolume(float volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class Car {
    private int id;
    private Engine engine;
    private String model;

    public Engine getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }

    public void setEngine(Engine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I was using this tutorial: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-form-handling-tutorial-and-example
to learn how to create form.

I created this form:

```
<form:form action="register" method="post" commandName="carForm">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Model:</td>
            <td><form:input path="model" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Volume:</td>
            <td><form:password path="volume" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

So is it any way to create Engine object with "volume" from form and later input this "Engine" object into "Car" object? Because each example of forms which I find in Google just creates one object.

Comment: Are you saying you want Car object with all the variables/getters/setters from Engine object?

Comment: I want the Car object to have Engine object inside. So I can use later for example car.engine.getVolume().

Answer (score 0):

Based on the commentary what i understand is you want the Engine object within a Car object so you can get specifics of Engine object.

You have two options:

1) Declare a Engine object within Car object as you did:

```
public class Car {

private Engine engine;

// getters and setters

}
```

2) Use the powerful inheritance capabilities.

```
public class Car extends Engine {

private int id;

private String model;

// extending Engine object gives you direct access to Engine objects variables

}
```

Use the inheritance model that way when you create the form for Car you call the Engine variables without the use of "engine.".

Answer (score 0):

I found solution of my problem, here is my form:

```
<form action="/Lab05/submitAdmissionForm.html" method="post">
    <p>
        Pojemnosc : <input type="number" step="0.1" name="volume" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Model : <input type="text" name="model" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And here is my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitAdmissionForm.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitAdmissionForm(@RequestParam("volume") float volume,
        @RequestParam("model") String model) {

    ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("AdmissionSuccess");
    Engine engine = new Engine();
    engine.setVolume(volume);
    Car car = new Car();
    car.setEngine(engine);
    car.setModel(model);
    modelView.addObject("msg", "Details submited by you: Volume: " + car.engine.getVolume() + " Model: " + car.getModel());
    return modelView;
}
```